# Sun Grid Engine's qmon -- "Cannot convert string..."

Tags: 13.10

I recently tried to run `qmon` (from **Sun Grid Engine** job queueing system) and when I do, I get a bunch of warnings that look like this:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "intro" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_job" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_queue" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_submit" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_cplx" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_host" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_cluster" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_sched" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_calendar" to type Pixmap
...
```

And then, when the GUI finally appears, all of the icons are replaced by a small dot.  I guess for some reason, the icons cannot be shown.  I tried to look for them in:

```
/usr/share/gridengine/pixmaps/
```

and indeed, the `*.xpm` files are there.

About half a year or so ago, it worked fine.  I guess something happened to my system during an upgrade or update that changed things.  Any ideas on what I should be looking for?  Any log files that could help me?

Thank you!

Ray

PS:  On Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: How did you install SGE? What repositories are you using?

Comment: By aptitude and I installed these packages:  gridengine-client, gridengine-common, gridengine-exec, gridengine-master, gridengine-qmon .  I guess the standard packages of Ubuntu 13.10; gridengine-common is version "6.2u5-7.1ubuntu2".  Are they too old?  I installed it a year ago and previously, it worked fine...some upgrade that I did broke something...

Comment: I am still having this issue with ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Any progress from upstream?

Comment: I never took the issue upstream.  As I mention below, I just installed Son of Grid Engine; even though it isn't officially a Ubuntu package, there are Ubuntu packages that are provided on the web site.  So installation is fairly easy and the above problem is gone.  Been running it for half a year with no problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overcome my problem and would like to share it with others.

Indeed, Bruno gave me some hints...that maybe I should be looking at other versions.

I had SGE installed via packages on a 12.04 system and a 13.10 system.  The 12.04 system is fine, but the 13.10 system gave me the problems described above.

My "solution" was to depart from the Ubuntu packages and install the Son of Grid Engine's latest version (8.1.6).  I can confirm that the above problem with qmon no longer exists for me.

Ray

Comment: It would be nice to know **how** did go about installing it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking...  Do you mean how did it go?  I posted my "answer" *after* I had got Son of Grid Engine working.  So, I was successful.  Or, do you mean the actual procedure for installing Son of Grid Engine?  It is easier than it sounds since they provide Debian-style .deb packages to install from.

Comment: No. What I meant was: Could you provide a step-by-step guide others can easily follow?

Comment: Oh!  I see!  I can easily defer it to the Son of Grid Engine web site:  https://arc.liv.ac.uk/trac/SGE .  Click on the latest one (which is 8.1.7 now) and download all of the .deb packages.  I also needed lesstif from http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/lesstif2 since it has been removed from the latest Ubuntu.  Then, install with "sudo dpkg -i", starting with "lesstif"; the rest probably doesn't matter.  After that, configuration is much like Sun of Grid Engine.  If you try and find out you're having problems, feel free to post a question...  Does this help?

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/414958/edit) your answer and add the information there.

Comment: Ummmm, the steps for installing Son of Grid Engine is a completely separate topic.  Granted, it solved my problem, but the actual steps of installing sound more like an answer to the question "How do you install it?".  Are you trying to set it up yourself?  If so, how about you phrase the problem you're having into a question?

Comment: In hindsight, I probably shouldn't have commented with so much detail yesterday.  Sorry about that!  I should have ask what problem you were having (i.e., have you tried installing it yet?  have you looked at the Son of Grid Engine's web site?) and given you help that way.

Comment: Don't feel sorry. This is a Question & Answer database we are trying to build. You can edit your questions, edit your answers and remove your comments at will. If you need guidance, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can also workaround the problem temporarily by creating few symbolic links in your home directory like this:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/icons/Qmon
cd $HOME/icons/Qmon
for f in /usr/share/gridengine/pixmaps/*; do ln -sf $f $(basename ${f%.xpm}); done
```