# Sun Grid Engine Qmon not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gui

After installing Sun Grid Engine and trying to run the qmon GUI, the system shows the following errors:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "intro" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_job" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_queue" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_submit" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_cplx" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_host" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_cluster" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_sched" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_calendar" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_user" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_pe" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_ckpt" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_ticket" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_prj" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_rqs" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_ar" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_browser" to type Pixmap
Warning: Cannot convert string "toolbar_exit" to type Pixmap
```

The qmon window appears yet is small and missing the buttons that are usually there.

The Ubuntu 14.04LTS is almost a fresh install without updates.
SGE qmon version installed is: 6.2u5-7.3

I did try to look for other answers. You may find a similar question issue to mine in: [Sun Grid Engine's qmon -- "Cannot convert string..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414092/sun-grid-engines-qmon-cannot-convert-string)

However, the answer provided by Ray regarding using Son of Grid Engine does not seem to work for me since sge_8.1.6_amd64.deb complains on dependencies - lesstif2 (>= 1:0.94.4)

I know that qmon and SGE worked well on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04LTS in April. Since there were no changes in the package that was last changed in February. I assume that my options are either:
A: Roll back to Ubuntu 12.04LTS
B: Wait until there is a fix to either Ubuntu or qmon
C: Build from source code

Option C seems too time consuming. Option B depends if there is someone on this list who can fix this. Option A seems the obvious choice, yet I rather upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04LTS If possible.

I hope there is a simple fix.

Comment: Your question is a bit old. There is a newer Son of Grid Engine version available: http://arc.liv.ac.uk/downloads/SGE/releases/8.1.9/ would that be an option? I was able to install it, first I had to install dependencies with `apt-get install tcsh db5.3-util libhwloc5 libjemalloc1 libmunge2 libxm4 libmotif-common`. However, running `qmon` failed for unknown reasons, quite possibly due to the lack of an actual grid or poorly done configuration.